# How to override footer template in a custom theme

Tags: magento2, template, theme, magento-community

I'm trying to override the footer template from a custom theme:

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/footer.phtml
```

Copying the file in my theme folder:

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<ThemeName>/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer.phtml
```

Then I removed all the content leaving only this:

```
<div class="footer-container">
</div>
```

But still I see the whole footer from the Magento's module.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out what was my problem.

Firstly I enabled the *template path hints mode* as described here:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/debug-theme.html

Thanks to path hints, I understood that the theme was not using the `footer.phtml` file, but was using `bugreport.phtml` and `copyright.phtml` both from the `magento-theme` module.

So I created these two templates:

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<ThemeName>/Magento_Theme/templates/html/bugreport.phtml
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<ThemeName>/Magento_Theme/templates/html/copyright.phtml
```

And now I'm able to override them from my custom theme.

Comment: Non of the files you said worked for me, I copied bugreport.phtml, copyright.phtml, absolute_footer.phtml, to use as a base, and non of them overwrite the <footer> block.   The bugreport never renders at all. both copyright and absolute_footer are under the <footer> node.

I'm still trying to find the right template.

Answer (score 14):

The configuration of the footer can be seen in this file:  `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

I was able to modify the footer declaration by creating my own default.xml file at `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<ThemeName>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="footer" template="html/footer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now my custom `footer.phtml` file is called instead of the containers/blocks defined in the original `default.xml`.

Comment: This is the best answer I've found if you want to create a footer from scratch. I haven't found how to copy the original phtml to use as a base to apply changes to it.

Comment: @StR That's the catch. There is no original phtml. See, the footer has a layout which divides it into columns. Now the stuff you see in your default footer, are injected in xml layouts files across the theme. basically, any extension could add or modify the content of your footer. Or at least that what I understood so far.